# Can an Xbox 360 read multiple partitions in a hard drive as different devices?

Tags: xbox-360

I have had a 500GB external hard drive connected to my xbox for a while and I realized that the xbox is only using 32GB, so after figuring that that is all it will use from any device, I was wondering if I were to add extra 32GB partitions to the drive would I be able to get the xbox to recognize them as different devices and thereby use more of the hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The Xbox 360 will recognize two USB devices and one 32 GB partition per device.

Comment: That seems like a bold claim, do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @RhysW Best I can find for them is this http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive. But speaking from experience, there is no supported way to partition a single drive multiple times that I've seen.